# sane not finding HP Scanjet G3110

Tags: drivers, usb, hp, scanner

I'm trying to install an HP Scanjet G3110 that I was given onto my printer server that is running Ubuntu 14.04.3. I've installed sane and the hp3900 backend that is listed as giving basic support for this model [here](http://www.sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html), but I cannot get sane to find the scanner. I checked that etc/sane.d/dll.conf contains a reference to hp3900 and that the hp3900.conf has

```
# HP Scanjet G3110
usb 0x03f0 0x4305
```

and that no other lines have the same usb 0x03f0 0x4305. The results of several relevant commands follow. What else should I be trying or does anyone have another lead I can track down?

`scanimage -L` returns:

```
No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something different,
check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and detected by the
sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate). Please read the documentation
which came with this software (README, FAQ, manpages).
```

`sane-find-scanner` returns:

```
  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

could not open USB device 0x03f0/0x4305 at 001:002: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0002 at 001:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0001 at 005:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0001 at 004:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x03f0/0x7604 at 003:002: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0001 at 003:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0001 at 002:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
  # No USB scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel driver for your USB host controller and have setup
  # the USB system correctly. See man sane-usb for details.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.

  # You may want to run this program as root to find all devices. Once you
  # found the scanner devices, be sure to adjust access permissions as
  # necessary.
```

`sudo sane-find-scanner` returns:

```
  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

  # No USB scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel driver for your USB host controller and have setup
  # the USB system correctly. See man sane-usb for details.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.
```

`lsusb` returns:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 03f0:4305 Hewlett-Packard ScanJet G3110
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 03f0:7604 Hewlett-Packard DeskJet 3940
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```